# Nexus 5x not showing up in adb on Win7

Tags: android, usb, adb

My Nexus 5X is not detecting in adb in Win7 machine but it's working on Ubuntu machine. I have latest drivers on Win7 (from Android SDK manager). It detects as MTP or Camera device but not in adb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Connect the Nexus 5X with your Win7 machine and switch in PTP (Photo transfer) Mode. 
Then it should hopefully install the right drivers.

Comment: Had the same problem (Nexus 5X on Win7x64). Switching to PTP didn't help. Switching to RNDIS fixed it. For me only when I put the device on RNDIS it's visible on ADB.

Comment: This worked for me. This doing this made Windows use the "Android Composite ADB Interface" and triggered the security message. Switching the phone back to "Just charging" changes the driver back to the "Google Nexus ADB Interface", which for some reason does not enable the use of adb